# In css, the @media doesn't effect ID elements

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website for a doctor, and he has some videos in YouTube he wanted me to add to his page. now it was really difficult for me to arrange the `<frame>` element properly so on mobile devices it would look good. I discovered the @media line in css, and I put all the frames I wanted to move in a div with an ID so on device all these frames would align vertically and on desktop view it would look horizontal.

```css
**#div-frame {
  ** position: relative;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-right: 69%;
  bottom: 1140px;
  margin-bottom: -1250px;
  line-height: 140px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .div-frame {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 60px;
    line-height: 140px;
  }
  .footer {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    background: #00ff21;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="about" class="sections3" style="padding-top:150px; padding-bottom:300px;  margin-top: 0px ;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="about-wrapper">
        <div class="col-s-9" style="">
          <h4 style="font-size:30px;" dir="rtl">
            סרטוני הסברה של ד"ר רם ירון

          </h4>
          <div class="about-content text-right">
            <div class="about-photo">
              <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/u07pee-IsgI" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>

            <div class="about-photo" style="position: relative; padding-top:60px; ">
              <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZTtNxfluyRo" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="about-photo" style="position: relative; padding-top:60px; ">
              <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LvPLpGe2qCw" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>

            <div class="div-frame">
              <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VonyJSD8yVA" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

              <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/upEUJkur7Co" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

              <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jjtBwdPusa8" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The css^ (the footer does work)

The id I'm trying to implement the change called id:"div-frame"
It's not repetitive (as I tried to change it to class as well.)
What can I do?

Comment: If you want to target an ID you have to include the ID in the HTML element. You only have the class declared.

Comment: if you want to change the display of each iframe, you should target them... apply a class to each one and then modify the class with media query, something like inline-block display when on desktop may help you

Comment: thank you Calvin nunes ! helped me alot!